# Estimating dynamic panel model with tricky survey data

Tags: survey, panel-data

I have a theoretical model that (given my ideal data set) could be taken to the data with a dynamic panel regression of the following form:

$s_{i,t} = \eta_i + \alpha a_{i,t} + \beta b_{i,t} + \gamma_1(a_{i,t})^2 + \gamma_2\cdot (b_{i,t})^2 + \gamma_3 (a_{i,t}b_{i,t})$

$a_{i,t} \equiv \sum_{\tau=1}^{t-1}s_{i,\tau}$

$b_{i,t} \equiv \sum_{\tau=1}^{t-1}x_{i,\tau}$

Note that the "dynamics" come from the lagged dependent variables in $a_{i,t}$. I have a panel which only includes observations on the key variables $s$ and $x$ for the most recent 10-20 periods for each individual $i$, so in terms of the model above, I don't observe $s_{i,1},...,s_{i,n}$, but I do observe $s_{i,n+1},...,s_{i,t}$ (and same for $x$). The value of $n$ is different for each individual, and unknown to me. For some context, this is weekly survey data of individuals from a 10-20 month survey, but I don't see any variables of interest before the start of the survey, so the summations you see above are truncated.

The quadratic/interaction terms are important, which causes problems given that I don't have a complete set of observations for each individual. In essence, because the "true" (read: model-predicted) slope coefficients depend on the full sum, and I only observe part of the sum in the data and don't know how much I observe, eliminating the fixed effects with differencing or demeaning doesn't control for the fact that each individual enters the survey with a different history, and thus should have different marginal effects.

So, two questions:

1) How can I properly identify the coefficients of interest given the data limitations described above?

2) Are standard dynamic panel techniques remotely useful here, given the problem I have described?

I'll be happy to elaborate more on the problem as needed. Any thoughts, comments or references are welcome. Thanks in advance!

John